# How to point registered domain to Google App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, registration, domain-name

I have a registered domain name from GoDaddy.com I need to point my Google app engine application to use this domain name for serving static pages. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions on using a custom domain with an App Engine application can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).